# Bitcoin scam: how screwed am I?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency

I was sent contact information from an agency for a job. After a ton of emails, the person seemed legitimate, and they then sent me a check for the work and supposedly to book flights and such for them. The check comes in, and I stupidly deposited it. The person then tells me to cash it out and buy bitcoin. A *red flag*.

I’m going to start off by saying I know dumb action depositing it by me.

If I just leave the money in my account, can the sender take any action against me?

I already submitted a claim with my bank.

Comment: There's no money. The check will bounce eventually.

Comment: any advice on moving forward? I have already submitted the claim. and I will be not touching that money.

Comment: Why is depositing it a bad idea? if it bounces then it bounces

Comment: When you say cheque for the work, do you mean they paid you for work you've already done?

Comment: @Aequitas Some banks allow you to spend the money the moment you deposit the check but **before the check clears**. Then when the check bounces **after** you've spent the money the bank will want the money back and now you owe the bank money while the people who sent you the cheque disappears.

Comment: @kevinN - as everyone has told you. For goodness sake, just **DON'T RESPOND** any more to the scammers.  NOTHING.  Be aware that you're not even talking to "one actual person", it's just a group of freelance, minimum wage poor bastards who follow the script on a given scam that's being run by some scammers.  JUST DON'T RESPOND.  If you do respond for some reason, the current person working the shift (who won't even vaguely remember you from the 1000s) will just paste in the next predetermined bit of the script. Honestly, JUST DONT send any more messages, give it a rest, if you haven't already!

Comment: I like this question because for once in all the scam questions the answer is *you're not screwed yet, good job in noticing the scam early enough*.

Comment: "How screwed am I?" - Yes.

Comment: @Aequitas Some banks have a fee for depositing a bad check.

Comment: @Aequitas When you deposit a check, you are representing to the bank that you are legally entitled to the funds. The OP knows that they are not entitled to the funds because they are likely either stolen or don't exist. In any event, he knows that he is not entitled to the funds -- that's why they asked him to buy bitcoin.

Comment: @Fattie on the contrary I would say keep responding in order to waste their time and money.

Comment: So someone seeming legitimate, sent a cheque for (some) work and to book flights and such… you deposited that cheque. Is there a problem thus far?

Telling you to buy Bitcoin should be a red flag, but whether it really matters should depend on the timing.

If you assume the deposit is legitimate, and right away use it to buy Bitcoin, you will be stuck.

If you let the deposit sit in your account for long enough, it will either clear, or be rejected or withdrawn

To determine what 'long enough' means, give all the details to your bank's security experts…

Comment: @Emobe seriously: don't do that.  (1) it's **technically illegal, as, factually, you know you are involved in money laundering** (2) they couldn't care less about one of 1000s of contacts making a few messages, it means nothing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz he has no reason to believe that he isn't legally entitled to the money. It's perfectly normal for companies to pay for your flights

Comment: @Aequitas It is absolutely not normal for a company to provide a check to their employee to deposit in the employee's personal account to have the employee buy bitcoin to be used to cover the employer's expenses. In any event, he knows that the funds are almost certainly stolen or non-existent which means he knows he's not entitled to them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The withdrawing and buying bitcoin part came later and is obviously not normal practice. But if I was in discussion with a company and they wanted me to fly out for an interview and were willing to send me a cheque to cover the costs, I would certainly think it was fine and would cash in the cheque. If it's a scam, then I've just lost the cost of the flights, and the scammers would've gotten nothing, so a bit of a weird scam.

Comment: @Aequitas Your example is inapposite because in that case, the money is yours to spend on flights as you wish. If they specified the travel agent and demanded you paid them cash, that would be a different story. Here, the OP was given specific directions on who to give the money to. They were acting as a conduit for someone else's payment.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree that OP isn't super clear in his description, but it seems to me it's exactly what is happening. I'm not sure what you have interpreted differently. It doesn't seem like OP was given directions, he was just given a cheque for what seems to be some work done, which is fairly common in longer interview processes and to book flights (of his own choosing? it seems), which I'm assuming is to meet the company for a face to face interview. Everything up to this point seems perfectly legitimate and even somewhat common.

Answer (score 55):

Good on you for catching the fraud immediately.

Immediately alert your bank to the suspected fraud.  I would even walk into a branch, as then, they will instantly grok that you're for real and not working a scam yourself.  Tell them you doubt the veracity of the check, cancel the deposit and ask them to waive fees.  (it doesn't actually work that way, you can't "stop payment" on a deposit, but it tells the bank where you're at on this, and asking for the fee waiver may well work!)

This is almost certainly a fake check overpayment scam - they've been doing these scams for *decades*.  They send you a check for more money than the item or service you are selling, and ask you to send back the overpayment. They pressure to send the money back FAST, and in a form which is non-reversible like Western Union, gift cards or Bitcoin.  They deliberately code their cheque with defective routing data so it takes *longer than usual* to bounce.

Now your bank has no idea how long a check takes to bounce/clear.  So the bank gives a *fixed amount of time* that is based on a TYPICAL clearing time and then releases the funds into your account.  **You didn't know that, did you?** You thought when it releases into your account, it has positively cleared... so you send the money on to them.  THEN the check bounces.

They know every vulnerability in our systems.  These scammers are *really good at it*.  We think of them as morons because of all the obvious errors we see in scam emails... but even those are [smartly chosen and deliberate](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/82814/secretly-smart-reason-scam-emails-are-poorly-written). Don't ever underestimate a scammer.

Comment: "your bank has no idea how long a check takes to bounce/clear." - **why not**?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because we live in a **world**, not a walled garden of European + a few Pacific Rim advanced democracies. Thus banking is limited by https://www.atlasandboots.com/travel-blog/tia-this-is-africa/

Comment: I as a Canadian citizen receive and deposit a cheque from another Canadian citizen (or if I am the sender), why should things that happen in Africa impact on the cheque clearance time? Like, I get that a cheque could have defective routing data. But why can't a Canadian bank instantly tell me "the numbers on this check *don't* indicate a standard cheque originating from a major Canadian bank with clearly valid routing data"?

Comment: @Karl I don't know, Check21 is the enabling technology that is supposed to make that possible. Why they haven't implemented it, I bet your banker would know.

Comment: Remember that comments are to ask for more information or to suggest improvements. Off-topic comments have been pruned.

Answer (score 7):

Scenario 1: Deposit check, send them money, then the check finally gets all the way through the banking system and bounces. You've lost your money and have very little recourse.

Scenario 2: The cash flow is genuine but illegal; you're being used to launder the money. You can be at serious legal risk.

Nobody legitimate will want to run their money through your bank account.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your bank and make sure they understand the situation: that you think the deposit was part of a scam and you have no intention of touching the money. The bank will have procedures for reversing the deposit. The key thing is to keep in communication with the bank and establish that you are acting in good faith.

The scammers may very well threaten you, but it will be a bluff. At most tell them you are working to reverse the deposit, but otherwise don't respond to them.

Comment: It would be funny to repeatedly tell them they need to pay additional fees to get their bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, if i just leave the money in my account can the sender take any action against me?

Depends on who you call "the sender".  The source of your communication, the one writing the cheque, or the owner of the account that the cheque is drawing its money from.  All can be different.

If there is no such account, the banks can take actions, essentially reversing the payment and adding a penalty for a bounced cheque.  If there is such an account, you can be reported to the police as a participating and abetting party in fraud, theft and/or money laundering.  That can come at significant cost.

You should at a minimum come clean with the bank, and it would not be amiss to also report to the police.